# Extract multiple values from a dataset by subsetting with a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vector

I have a data frame called "Navi", with 72 rows that describe all possible combinations of three variables f,g and h.

```
head(Navi)
   f g h
1  40.00000              80  0.05
2  57.14286              80  0.05
3  74.28571              80  0.05
4  91.42857              80  0.05
5 108.57143              80  0.05
6 125.71429              80  0.05
```

I have a dataset that also contains these 3 variables f,g and h along with several others.

```
head(dataset1[,7:14])
# A tibble: 6 x 8
          h                f                  g     L1   L2          Ref1       Ref2              FR
        <dbl>           <dbl>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>
1        0.02              20                100    53    53        0.501                2.00               2  
2        0.02              20                260    67    67        0.200                5.01               5.2
3        0.02              20                420    72    71        0.128                7.83               8.4
4        0.02              20                580    72    72        0.0956              10.5               11.6
5        0.02              20                740    73    73        0.0773              12.9               14.8
6        0.02              20                900    72    71        0.0655              15.3               18
```

What I'm trying to do is:
for each row in the combinations data frame, filter the dataset by the three variables f,g and h.
Then, if there are exact matches, give me the matching rows of this dataset, then extract the values in the columns "L1" and "FR" in this dataset and calculate the average of them. Save the average value in the vectors "L_M2" and "FR_M2"
If there aren't exact matches, give me the rows where f,g,h in the dataset are closest to f,g,h from the data frame. Then extract all values for L and FR in these rows, and calculate the average. Save the average value in the vectors "L_M2" and "FR_M2".

What I've already tried:
I created two empty vectors where the extracted values shall be saved later on.
Then I am looping over every row of the combinations data frame, filtering the dataset by f,g and h.
The result would be multiple rows, where the values for f,g and h are the same in the dataset as in the row of the combinations data frame.

```
L_M2 <- vector()
FR_M2 <- vector()
for (i in 1:(nrow(Navi))){
  matchingRows[i] <- dataset1[dataset1$P == "input$varP"
                              & dataset1$Las == input$varLas
                              & dataset1$Opt == input$varO
                              & dataset1$f == Navi[i,1]
                              & dataset1$g == Navi[i,2]
                              & dataset1$h == Navi[i,3]]
}
```

The thing is, I don't know what to do from here on. I don't know how to check for rows with closest values by multiple variables, if there are no exact matches...
I only did something more or less similar in the past, but I only checked for the closes "g" value like this:

```
L_M2 <- vector()
FR_M2 <- vector()
for (i in 1:(nrow(Navi))){
  matchingRows[i] <- dataset1[dataset1$P == "input$varP"
                              & dataset1$Las == input$varLas
                              & dataset1$Opt == input$varO
                              & dataset1$f == Navi[i,1]
                              & dataset1$g == Navi[i,2]
                              & dataset1$h == Navi[i,3]]

  for (i in 1:(nrow(Navi)){
  Differences <- abs(Navi[i,2]- matchingRows$G)
  indexofMin <- which(Differences == min (Differences))
  L_M2 <- append(L_M2, matchingRows$L[[indexofMin]], after = length(L_M2))
  FR_M2 <- append(FR_M2, matchingRows$FR[[indexofMin]], after = length(FR_M2))
}
```

So can anybody tell me how to achieve this extraction process?I am still pretty new to R, so please tell me If I made a rookie mistake or forgot to include some crucial information. Thank you!

Comment: What criteria you are looking for "If there aren't exact matches, give me the rows where f,g,h in the dataset are closest to f,g,h from the vector".

Comment: let's say the first row of the Navi data frame is (40, 80, 0.05), and in the dataset1 there is no such row where this is true, give me the rows that are the next close, for example there could be rows where f=45, g=78 and h= 0.03

Answer (score 1):

First convert your data into dataframe (if not done before).

```
Navi <- data.frame(Navi)
Savi <- data.frame(dataset1[,7:14])
```

Then use merge to filter your lines:

```
df1 <- merge(Navi, Savi, by = c("f","g","h"))
```

Save "L1" and "FR" average from df1:

```
Average1 <- ((df1$L1+df1$FR)/2)
```

Get you your new Navi dataframe which doen not have exact match on f,g,h columns

```
Navi_new <- Navi[!duplicated(rbind(df1, Navi))[-seq_len(nrow(df1))], ]
```

For comparing the values with nearest match:

```
A1 <- vapply(Navi_new$f, function(x) x-Savi$f, numeric(3))
A2 <- apply(abs(A1), 2, which.min)
B1 <- vapply(A1$g, function(x) x-Savi$g, numeric(3))
B2 <- apply(abs(B1), 2, which.min)
C1 <- vapply(B1$g, function(x) x-Savi$g, numeric(3))
C2 <- apply(abs(C1), 2, which.min)
```

You can use C2 dataframe to get the average of "L1" and "FR" like 3 steps back.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for the answer! When trying out your answer, I get an error message for "Navi_new <- Navi[!duplicated(rbind(df1, Navi))[-seq_len(nrow(df1))], ]" : Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match" because my Navi dataframe only has the three columns f,g,h and the df1 has all the columns that dataset1/Savi has. Can you further explain why you used rbind here? I need the other columns in order to get the values for L1 and FR later on, so I can't just cut the dataframe.